# Is there an algorithm for determining the identity of an individual, based on their genome and the genome of distant relatives?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, bioinformatics

I've been thinking recently about the Golden State Killer case, in which a crime was solved by comparing a killer's DNA sample with known samples in a public genetic database. The cousin of the killer was in the database, leading to an arrest. I wanted to try to understand/formalize this process a bit further, but ran into some roadblocks.

Imagine you have access to a graph $G = (V, E)$, called the phylogenetic graph. It contains the genetic relationships for all humans, where there is an edge from nodes $A \rightarrow B$ if $Parent(B) = A$. Let $q(v)$ be the genome of some node $v \in V$, and $q(V) := \{ q(v) \  | \  v \in V \}$.

Imagine now that you have a database, $(D, q(D))$, containing the genomes of $D \subset V$ individuals, where $|D| << |V|$. You can imagine that D might contain the culprits second, third, fourth, fifth cousins etc.

With that set up, consider some unknown individual $x \in V$. You don't know $x$, but you do know their genome $q(x) \in q(V)$. You wish to recover $x \in V$. You also have access to a similarity function, $sim : q(V) \times q(V) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, which given two genomes, returns a measure of their relatedness. You can imagine sim being related to SNP coincidence, or just anything that can give a measure of relatedness between two individuals.

$\textbf{Questions}:$

1. Given $G = (V, E), (D, q(D)), q(x)$, what are some good methods for recovering $x$?
2. If you only have partial information of $G$ (corresponding to the case where you don't have the full phylogenetic graph), how can you recover $x$?
3. How large does D need to be, in order to identify any arbitrary $x \in V$?

It seems to me if this algorithm is feasible to implement, then having a (partial) phylogenetic graph of a population, as well as a few reference genomes, could allow one to identify individuals on their genomes alone...

---

The obvious algorithm to me (for 1.) is just to compute
$$v^* = \sup_{v \in V} - \sum_{d \in D}[sim(q(v), q(d)) - sim(q(x), q(d))]$$, where $v^*$ is the individual who minimizes the difference between the similarity of q(x) to q(D).

Is there a better way to go about this? Maybe it depends on the properties of $sim$.

Comment: You're presumably going to need to make some assumptions about how the "parent" relationship is related to the "sim" metric.

Comment: You're totally right- I've edited the above.